# Has kafka implemented the future of idempotent producer

Tags: message-queue, apache-kafka

When I'm scanning kafka's [document](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html), I see an article about [idempotent producer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Idempotent+Producer), which is a very cool future. However, I am not sure whether this has been implemented in version 0.9 or is just a proposal for future release. Is there anyone know about this?

In the first document section **4.6 Message Delivery Semantics**

> These are not the strongest possible semantics for publishers.
>   Although we cannot be sure of what happened in the case of a network
>   error, it is possible to allow the producer to generate a sort of
>   "primary key" that makes retrying the **produce request idempotent**. This
>   feature is not trivial for a replicated system because of course it
>   must work even (or especially) in the case of a server failure. With
>   this feature it would suffice for the producer to retry until it
>   receives acknowledgement of a successfully committed message at which
>   point we would guarantee the message had been published exactly once.
>   We hope to **add this in a future Kafka version**.

This looks very vaguer, is this imply hasn't implemented yet?

Comment: I'm also trying to figure out if this is a feature. Do you know, or do you have a work-around?

Comment: The feature is not yet implemented. See the [JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1436) for more. It seems that the focus is now on [exactly-once semantics](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/issues/114), so this'll likely be implement as part of that initiative.

Comment: @TianxiangXiong, Exactly-once semantics is one way to implement idempotence. We can understand idempotent operator as calling that  methods over and over again, it effectively the same with calling one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idempotent producer was implemented finally in version 0.11.0.0
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4817

Read this article as well on how Kafka provides "exactly once" guarantees:
https://www.confluent.io/blog/exactly-once-semantics-are-possible-heres-how-apache-kafka-does-it/